# Can this isometric embedding $\mathbb{R}^2/S_2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be generalised to higher dimensions?

Tags: metric-spaces, group-actions

Endow $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric.
The symmetric group with two elements, $S_2$, acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by swapping the coordinates.
Endow $\mathbb{R}^2/S_2$ with the quotient metric, which is again a metric space.
Then the map
$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathbb{R}^2/S_2 &\rightarrow& \mathbb{R}^2
\\
[(x,y)] &\mapsto& (\min(x,y), \max(x,y))
\end{matrix}
$$
is an isometry.
Is there an extension of this to one of the following settings?

1. The symmetric group $S_n$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by permuting coordinates
2. The cyclic group with $n$ elements $\mathbb{Z}_n$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^n$ by cyclic permutation of coordinates
3. The group actions of $S_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}_n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n_+$, i.e. vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all entries being positive real numbers

Answer (score 2):

You can get an isometry $\Bbb R^n/S_n\to \Bbb R^n$ by sorting the elements of the input tuple.
More percisely, you map

$$[(x_1,...,x_n)]\;\mapsto\;(x_{i_1},...,x_{i_n})$$

so that $x_{i_1}\le x_{i_2} \le\cdots \le x_{i_n}$.

---

The quotient $\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z_n$ is essentially isometric to a product of 2-dimensional cones, which is not isometric to any subset of $\Bbb R^n$ (except for $n=2$), so there is no such isometry.

Here is what I mean precisely: let $C_k$ be the infinite 2-dimensional cone surface with circular link and apex angle $\alpha=2\arcsin(1/k)$, a finite part of which is depicted below.

[image]

The apex angle is chosen in such a way, so that when you unroll the cone, the mantle will go around $2\pi/k$ of the full circle.

$$\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z_n\cong
\begin{cases}
[0,\infty]\times\Bbb R \times\prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-1} C_{n/\!\gcd(n,k)} & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
\phantom{[0,\infty]\times}\,\,\,\!\Bbb R \times \prod_{k=1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} C_{n/\!\gcd(n,k)} & \text{if $n$ is odd}\\
\end{cases},$$

So for example, you will find

\begin{align}
\Bbb R^2/\Bbb Z_2&\cong \Bbb R\times\Bbb [0,\infty], \\
\Bbb R^3/\Bbb Z_3&\cong C_3\times\Bbb R, \\
\Bbb R^4/\Bbb Z_4&\cong C_4\times \Bbb R\times \Bbb [0,\infty], \\
\Bbb R^5/\Bbb Z_5&\cong C_5\times C_5 \times \Bbb R, \\
\Bbb R^6/\Bbb Z_6&\cong C_6\times C_3\times \Bbb R\times\Bbb [0,\infty], \\ &\;\vdots
\end{align}

This decomposition results from the decomposition of $\Bbb R^n$ into  [(real) irreducible invariant subspaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace) of $\Bbb R^n$ w.r.t. the action of $\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: I convinced myself that the the map $\mathbb{R}^n/S_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ that you wrote down in an isometry, using induction and the two-dimensional case. Is $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}_n$ isometric to a cone in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ for $m \geq n+1$? If so, what is the link of the cone?

Comment: @user505117 What do you mean by "link" of a cone?

Comment: Let $L$ be a manifold with metric $g_L$. The cone over $L$ is then the manifold $C=(0,\infty) \times L$ endowed with the metric $g_c=dt^2+t^2 g_L$, where $t$ is a coordinate on $(0,\infty)$. The metric extends to $\overline{C}=[0,\infty) \times L/\sim$, where is defined by $(0,x) \sim (0,y)$ for all $x,y \in L$. $\overline{C}$ is also a cone. $L$ is called the link of the cone $C$ and $\overline{C}$. Another way to ask my question would be: what is the equation of the cone?

Comment: Thanks for the update to your answer, I understand the claim. But I don't know how to prove it. Can you help me by saying what the map from $\mathbb{R}^n/\mathbb{Z}_n$ to $C \times \mathbb{R}^{n-2}$ is?

Comment: @M.Winter, 3. seems to suggest that the eigenvalues of an endomorphism $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, that generates the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ action, are $(\zeta,\zeta^{-1},1,...,1)$ for $\zeta=\exp(2 \pi i/n)$. However, my calculations show that they are $(\zeta,\zeta^2,\dots,\zeta^n=1)$. Did I misunderstand your point 3?

Comment: @deepfloe You are right. This seems to make the quotient space much more complicated. Apparently $\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z_n$ looks more like a cartesian product of cones of different shapes, and (in odd dimensions) another copy of $\Bbb R$. And the types of these cones varies by dimension. E.g.
\begin{align}
\Bbb R^3/\Bbb Z_3&\cong C_3\times\Bbb R, \\
\Bbb R^4/\Bbb Z_4&\cong C_4\times C_2, \\
\Bbb R^5/\Bbb Z_5&\cong C_5\times C_5 \times \Bbb R, \\
\Bbb R^6/\Bbb Z_6&\cong C_6\times C_3\times C_2, \\ &\;\vdots
\end{align}
where $C_n$ denotes the cone with the apex angle $2\arcsin(1/n)$.

Comment: @user505117 Sorry, I had to rework my answer in the case $\Bbb R^n/\Bbb Z_n$. It is now more complicated to write down the isometry. I might do it if I find time.

Comment: @deepfloe Ok, my comment was still not correct, but hopefully the answer is now correct. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Please correct me if a I am wrong but to me it seems your argument goes like:
1) Split $\mathbb{R}^n=V_1 \oplus \dots \oplus V_k$ into invariant subspaces wrt to the action of $G=\mathbb{Z}_n$
2) As topological spaces,
$\mathbb{R}^n/G\cong V_1/G  \oplus \dots \oplus V_k/G$
However, I disagree with 2). Check for example the action of $\{1,-1\}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @deepfloe Yes, that is my argument. What do you mean with 2)? Note that my comment was wrong, check the answer instead. And I think no $\Bbb Z_n$ has the action of $\{1,-1\}$ on $\Bbb R^2$ (or does it? :o), but again, please correct me, or elaborate what you mean exactly.

Comment: I meant to say that my statement 2) is not true for general $G$ acting on a vector space. One counterexample I had in mind is ${\pm 1}$ acting on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by multiplication. 
Then $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\oplus \mathbb{R}$ with $\{\pm 1\}$ acting on each component by multiplication is an equivariant splitting. However $\mathbb{R}^2/\{\pm 1\}\neq \mathbb{R}/\{\pm 1\}\oplus \mathbb{R}/\{\pm 1\}$ .
You are right that is not the action considered in the question here, my point was just that 2) is not true for general $G$.

Comment: @deepfloe I understand. Interesting observation. Might have something to do with the fact that this decomposition is not unique for such group action.

Comment: But are you convinced that 2) holds in the case of $\mathbb{Z}_n$? If so, why?